# What is Chrome inspector stylesheet called (index)

Tags: html, wordpress, css, google-chrome

I'm editing a wordpress template for my site, and when I look in chrome inspector, a lot of styles are coming from this `(index)`

[image]

I can't figure out where or what it is. It doesn't seem to be a stylesheet. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

These css rules are coming from the currrent file you are. In your example, you have the style in your index and it is bettwen css tags:

```
<style>
~~ your css rules ~~
</style>
```

If you can't find this, I'd recommend a search on searchmonkey.exe (https://www.google.com.br/search?q=searchmonkey+download&oq=searchmonkey+download&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.4704j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Search for the classes names and it may return the file and where it is placed.

I'll be here if you have any other doubt.

Comment: I can't figure out where the box-shadow is coming from on .site-header on novicedock.com

Comment: As per my check, the page is using Wordpress so it's dynamic. Do you have any custom css plugin that may give you this rules? If you don't, verify the theme settings. When you look at the <style> that stores this code, you see :: <style type="text/css" id="**lighthouse-header-css** (YOUR THEME CLASS NAME)">